HTTP Error 500, unable to handle this request on website and wp admin dashboard
My website and WP-admin dashboard hosted on AWS Lightsail instance is displaying a "HTTP Error 500" after I replaced my Wordpress files except the wp-content and wp-config.php file, I have replaced  the code in the .htaccess file to the default code and I've renamed the plugins and themes folders in the wp-content folder but the error still persists, please any help will really be appreciated. Thank you!
I've renamed the themes and plugins folders in the wp-content folder, I have replaced the code to the default in the .htaccess file, I rebooted the AWS Lightsail instance, the WP-Config.php file only has these lines of code
<?php

//Begin Really Simple SSL session cookie settings
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
//END Really Simple SSL
 // Added by Hummingbird
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress' );
/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress' );
/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'd071a120ab47cbb5ad4da2dd7f9784db58a3d35ad80f9f4730db0501ceb555ab' );
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306' );
/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'yR8t#+|ZCYM|-B^mo=NTI)9vt!R0^BGdktuQc{t)] Jp@e/itglqQX:d/5Amb}kI' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '?A1KYn>1EiJPWPlPQBy^Wc]14R#h{{qYK=E6LcJy:HiS-RLe|[F%_<&q#CA^7DEB' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '+tstDuW^mXp.%Em%NIuC|rK)m,9j;NF<D&kx1eGBo-5$5G=Et2v8=|n;!-x@xsv,' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'SLdrU 4uW/.F;.Cg@16WlI#4_t&XrPoAY*3GO.IxE?D>^ZgCLihI/ZOKYX-uoWMa' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'yATQ]gFq6mBK##QdF8FakX1D/EM3@23CwEd6z_ ;Sh|GCM90x@M~Avf26xSXav2P' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', ',)-77Pn_F2J-twnb_QQumdMe^AJ#(NXc>/d`j)DovR];|xn}1RV`#0=_/Az{ESuL' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '1U]}6:&UEPzF*[nU3AncYB%NMOn9#XTGE,)5n5q _J9!VFR*OsL@{r}@Q5|nrDyb' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'uBg6=3AVv:LJaw (jH];9<<,{gM;lCn#%7t1)d)QeLN7Q?JRp[Y8{U>_yk7E*L/[' );
/**#@-*/
/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
/**
 * The WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME options are configured to access from any hostname or IP address.
 * If you want to access only from an specific domain, you can modify them. For example:
 *  define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
 *  define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
 *
 */require'/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/css/color-pickor.css';
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1';
}
// define('WP_HOME','https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
// define('WP_SITEURL','https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://innov8hub.ng');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://innov8hub.ng');
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
/**
 * Disable pingback.ping xmlrpc method to prevent WordPress from participating in DDoS attacks
 * More info at: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/troubleshooting/xmlrpc-and-pingback/
 */
if ( !defined( 'WP_CLI' ) ) {
    // remove x-pingback HTTP header
    add_filter("wp_headers", function($headers) {
        unset($headers["X-Pingback"]);
        return $headers;
    });
    // disable pingbacks
    add_filter( "xmlrpc_methods", function( $methods ) {
        unset( $methods["pingback.ping"] );
        return $methods;
    });
}



It has been resolved, there was a line in the wp-config.php file    require'/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/css/color-pickor.css'; . I just removed the line and everything works fine now. Thank you
